# Javascript scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

```
var preGameRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var preGameData;

preGameRequest.open("GET", "/matches/live.json");
preGameRequest.onload = function() {
    preGameData = JSON.parse(preGameRequest.responseText);
}
preGameRequest.send();
console.log(preGameData);   // main problem is here
```

Here is my code. I defined preGameData as global and tried to save /matches/live.json file's data into preGameData. And when I try to console.log(preGameData) from outside of the scope (like in the code section) I get 'undefined' as a return. And if I try to console.log(preGameData) from inside of the scope it works. I don't really know what's going on.

Comment: You might want to read some tutorials on asynchronous JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work:

```html
preGameRequest.onload = function() {
    preGameData = JSON.parse(preGameRequest.responseText);
    console.log(preGameData);
}
```

**The reason:** is that **preGameRequest.send() function operates asynchronous**.

When the browser tries to execute console.log() (in your example), the http response is not recieved yet, and the variable is really *undefined*.

But if you place console.log() inside of the handler (as in my example), it would be executed at moment, when the response is already recieved (straight in the onload() handler). And that's why the variable preGameData would be defined already.